# Only fast travel to houses or festival?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

In Forza Horizon 4, I am unable to fast travel to arbitrary points on the map and can only go to either a festival or an owned house.

I seem to remember previous horizon games allowing this.

Do I have to get a certain number of fast travel boards to unlock it? Can it be unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to get a certain number of fast travel boards to unlock it?

Fast travel boards only effect the cost of fast travel, and there are no expanded fast travel benefits from smashing them.

> Can it be unlocked?

Yes.

Fairlawn Manor, located below on the map:

(spoiler warning, if you want to encounter this location on your own then don't hover)

> [image]

will allow you to fast travel (for a price) to any location on the map. In addition to that perk, it also comes with 10 super wheelspins and a top hat.

[image]